# Predicting the Success of a tweet

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, social-network

I want to predict the success of a tweet.
In my case a tweet is successful when the sum of the number of favorites and the number of retweets is greater than 5. So my outcome value y is:

**y= 
if((retweets + favorites) >5   ==1**
else == 0

Therefore I created the following dataset:
(This sample just shows the data for one twitter user and so friendCount etc. is always the same. In my real dataset there are thousand of users and their last tweets)

```
head(dataTrain)

+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| friendsCount | followersCount | nbTweets     | at | rt | link | nchar           | nwords           | r_nachar_words  | hash | no_hash | hash_mean    | y |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| 0.7105428815 | 0.7105428815   | 0.7105428815 | 0  | 0  | 1    | -20.471.177.338 | -125.525.459.396 | -22.192.436.207 | 0    | 0       | -0,777283372 | 1 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| 0.7105428815 | 0.7105428815   | 0.7105428815 | 1  | 0  | 1    | -0.5838923895   | -0.68260381719   | 0.2862346486    | 1    | 1       | -0,330839739 | 0 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| 0.7105428815 | 0.7105428815   | 0.7105428815 | 1  | 1  | 1    | -0.6884084855   | -125.525.459.396 | 19.565.534.949  | 1    | 5       | 0,562047528  | 1 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| 0.7105428815 | 0.7105428815   | 0.7105428815 | 0  | 0  | 1    | -0.2006667041   | -0.10995304042   | -0.2562620706   | 1    | 3       | 0,6364548    | 0 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| 0.7105428815 | 0.7105428815   | 0.7105428815 | 0  | 0  | 1    | 0.9490103521    | 122.623.210.539  | -0.6388650200   | 0    | 0       | -0,777283372 | 1 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
| 0.7105428815 | 0.7105428815   | 0.7105428815 | 0  | 0  | 1    | 0.3567524747    | 0.08093055184    | 0.4350079872    | 1    | 2       | 0,227214803  | 1 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+----+----+------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+--------------+---+
```

So the dataset contains the features:

- friendsCount (how many people does the user follow?)
- followersCount (how many people do follow the user?)
- nbTweets (how many tweets did the user send in the last weeks?)
- at (does the tweet contain a @? )
- link (does the message contain a link? )
- nchar (number of characters in the tweet)
- nwords (number of words in the tweet)
- r_nachar_words (ratio betweent chars and words)
- hash (does the messsage contain a hashtag? )
- no_hash (how many hashtags does the message contain? )
- hash_mean (what is the mean length of the hashtags? )
- y (was the sum of number of favorites and number of retweets greater than 5? )

At the moment I use a Support Vector Machine for creating the model and the SVMlight algorithm. But it does not scale really well and is very slow. I get a accuracy of about 80% but very poor values for Sensitivity and Kappe.

My Questions:

- What would be a better approach for creating the model? Would you prefer for example a deep learning network instead of a SVM?
- Do I use enough features? Could you think of other features which could increase the performance of my model?

Comment: Neither one of these publications are concerned with features of tweets but model attention as a reinforcing stochastic process which may be relevant to your work.

T. Onaga and S. Shinomoto. Bursting transition in a linear self-exciting point process. arXiv, January 2014. URL http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5186.

Hua-Wei Shen, Dashun Wang, Chaoming Song, and Albert-L ́aszl ́o Barab ́asi. Modeling and predicting popularity dynamics via reinforced poisson processes. arXiv, 1 2014. URL http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0778.

Comment: How many people have 0.7105428815 friends and equally many followers? Very little in the example data appears to be related to the descriptions of it.

Comment: The sample data is normalized and the sample just shows the data for one twitter user. In my real dataset there are thousands of users and their last tweets. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: Have you tried logistic regression?

Comment: Yes. But a SVM did perform better.

Comment: If there is a chance that there will be the same users in the test and the train set, I would recommend to treat such users differently: you should be able to build a more accurate model for specific user. Also, tweets linking to an image are probably more popular, you can try this feature.